# Formulas for percentage gain/loss equivalent to formula for percentage change?

Tags: percentages

Can you please tell me whether the *percentage change* formula below can be used in place of both the *percentage gain* formula and the *percentage loss* formula below? Thank you in advance.

I have seen that *percentage gain* can be calculated using this formula:

$$\frac{2\text{nd value}}{\text{original value}} (-1) (\cdot 100)$$

e.g. original value = 10, 2nd value = 12
12/10 -1 x 100 = 20% percentage gain

and *percentage loss* as follows:

$$1 - \frac{\text {second value}}{\text{original}} \cdot 100$$

e.g. original value = 12, 2nd value = 10
1- 10/12 x 100 = 20% loss

Do their results differ from the result the following *percentage change* formula gives? Or can this be used to replace both formulas? :
$$\frac{\text{new value} - \text{old value}}{\text{new value}}$$

Comment: could you please clarify what second value, as second value etc is?

Comment: I have tried to clarify, hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Percentage change is always calculated with respect to original value.

Hence percentage change=$\frac{(new\ value)-(old\ value)}{old\ value}\times 100$

As for whether this formula can replace both for loss and gain remember that this would be you formula for gain i.e., if there is a gain then there is no change of formula while if there is a loss then to calculate loss percentage you need to take negative of this formula

%Gain=$\frac{(new\ value)-(old\ value)}{old\ value}\times 100$

%Loss=$\frac{(old\ value)-(new\ value)}{old\ value}\times 100$ to ensure that you get a positive output.